# sys.exit(): is there a less extreme alternative?

Tags: python

I was hoping to get some kind of advice regarding the use of `sys.exit()`. I have used `sys.exit()` to stop a script from running any further:

My code:

```
if  x != 20:
    query = raw_input("X does not equal 20. Do you want to continue? (Y/N)")
    if query in ['y', 'Y']:
        pass
    else:
        sys.exit()
```

I have done some searching (and am still searching) but I was hoping to gain some clarity regarding the best practices use of `sys.exit()`. Is there something a little less extreme than killing the script? I'm considering the combination of extra loop and a more inquisitive question.

Comment: Why not use `return` or `break` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is used at the beginning of your script (as mentioned by you). Use the coding pattern written below. And use `return` instead of `sys.exit` (actually since you are exiting from the script itself thereby terminating the process altogether `sys.exit` is not a bad practice).

Whether you use `return` or `sys.exit` return appropriate integer. its a good practice.

```
def do_something():
    //process something
    return 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    query = raw_input("Do you want to continue? (Y/N)")
    if query.lower() == 'y':
        //do something
        do_something()
    else:
        print 'ERROR: Cant Understand Input. It has to be (Y/N). Exiting...'
        return 0
```

Comment: Code is placed near the beginning of my script.

Comment: @JackHansen  you could use `main()` or do something like I posted above.

Answer (score 4):

Place your code in the main() function:

```
def main():
    // your code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then you can exit from your script just by **return**

Comment: Great idea. This idea turned up in my research too. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

As other commenters have noted, a function provides you the option of using return to bail out from anywhere in the script and that's probably the best choice - I just thought I'd mention one piece of trivia:

Technically sys.exit raises a SystemExit exception.  You can catch a SystemExit with an ordinary try-catch, effectively 'canceling' the exit if you want to. This might come in handy if you have more complex code in which a low level function might not have enough context to make a good decision but higher level code may want to step in and clean up.

People from C/C++ and lots of other languages get hives from this tactic but it's not uncommon in Pythonland.  It's *not* a good idea to use exceptions for flow control in general but if you are using other people's functions, or combining smaller scripts into a larger application, it may be useful.

Don't forget, btw, that if control falls through to the bottom of your script it will just return 'None' anyway, so in your example:

```
if  x != 20:
    query = raw_input("X does not equal 20. Do you want to continue? (Y/N)")
    if query in ['y', 'Y']:
        // do something
```

is the same as

```
if  x != 20:
    query = raw_input("X does not equal 20. Do you want to continue? (Y/N)")
    if query in ['y', 'Y']:
        // do something
    else:
        sys.exit()
```

EXCEPT for the fact that you could try/catch around the second but not the first... though I assume your example is snipped from a larger sample where return is the better escape route

Comment: Thank you. This info is really helpful. You've clarified a lot of the confusion I had when reading the Python docs.